# CoInitializeSecurity on .NET 6.0 cannot be called in time

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-6.0, win32com

I have been using the CoInitializeSecurity API  function on several of my projects without any problem, but today I am facing a strange behavior that would like to share and see if someone get it working.
It is a known fact that you have to use this call as earlier as possible in your project, and So I do, but the exact same code works fine in .NET 5 (or any earlier) and does not run on .NET 6, so I am out of ideas on how to fix it.

Furthermore, doing extra testing, I found out that it works fine in a ConsoleApp using .NET 6 but it does NOT when using WinForms app.
Looks like in .NET 6 they changed something that is stopping this call to be successfully.

I have created a dummy repo which all the alternatives, that can be accessed here: https://github.com/creizlein/CoInitializeSecurity

I am calling the function as earlier as possible, in the form Load event or even after InitializeComponent or before, but it doesnt make any difference when using .NET 6, it works wonders on any of them using .NET 5, .NET Core 3, and old Frameworks.

Anyone knows how to get around this and get it working using .NET 6 and a WinFormsApp?

Btw, error is always the same: `Security must be initialized before any interfaces are marshalled or unmarshalled. It cannot be changed once initialized.`

Comment: You should open an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues, you're unlikely to get an answer for that question here.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I just opened an issue in there, we will see how it goes. 
https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/7536

Comment: Call it in your `Program.Main`, before the `Application.Run` call

Comment: @Charlieface i did try that as well, and indeed it makes a slightly difference, it works on .NET 6 but only if you ran outside the debugger, if ran within VS then it makes no difference, it fails...
Strange part is that it fails just for .NET 6, if you switch the target to 5.0 it works even within the VS IDE

Comment: You're clearly calling it late and should call it before anything else, but I think it's more a Visual Studio 2022 issue than a .NET issue. VS 2022 loads dlls into your process: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll, Microsoft.Extensions.DotNetDeltaApplier.dll, etc. if you disable Hot Reload (Project Properties / Debug) it should work (this is probably using COM to communicate between app & reloaded)

Comment: Those are details, you shouldn't have to guess how early is too late or what debugger options to enable, there should be a standard way to get this function called. Perhaps through an assembly attribute.

Comment: I guess why do you need to call it anyway?

Comment: @SimonMourier  , that did the trick actually, thanks a lot! I disabled Hot Reload and it started to work for .NET 6  , odd part is that it works for .NET 5 whatever you have Hot Reload or not, but I will assume thats a new feature thingy...
Thanks a lot, you you can submit it as a Solution as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon Mourier provided the trick in a comment:

> You're clearly calling it late and should call it before anything else, but I think it's more a Visual Studio 2022 issue than a .NET issue. VS 2022 loads dlls into your process: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll, Microsoft.Extensions.DotNetDeltaApplier.dll, etc. if you disable Hot Reload (Project Properties / Debug) it should work (this is probably using COM to communicate between app & reloaded)

That did the trick actually; thanks a lot! I disabled Hot Reload and it started to work for .NET 6. The odd part is that it works for .NET 5 whether you have Hot Reload or not, but I will assume that's a new feature?