# Why does thread pool start with 2 threads in debug-build-run?

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, asynchronous, threadpool

Code :

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int threadCount = ThreadPool.ThreadCount;
        Console.WriteLine($"thread count : {threadCount}");
        
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1, 2));
        
        List<Task> tlist = new();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"repeat {i}");
            
            tlist.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                threadCount = ThreadPool.ThreadCount;
                Console.WriteLine($"thread count : {threadCount}");
                return FuncAsync();
            }));
            Console.WriteLine($"repeat end {i}");
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tlist.ToArray());
    }

    public static async Task FuncAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FuncAsync");
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work only when 'run' with 'release' build.

|  | Debugging | Running |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Debug build | work | unwork |
| Release build | work | work |

[image: Screenshot]

In first of, sorry to my pool English ability ...

I tring to know how async method working when thread pool's max capability is 1.
But I met some unexpected error.

When I try to run with debug build, thread pool start with already filling with 2 thread.
[image: Screenshot]

So, there's no affordable thread in `ThreadPool`, then it doesn't work. Just stop infinitely ...
[image: Screenshot]

But this situation never occur when start with,

1. debug with debug build
2. debug with release build
3. run with release build

Anyone know why this situation occurred?

Comment: Note that this reproduces without the `async`. Also, when I reproduce it in VS, I don't get quite the same output: I don't see the `FuncAsync` printed.

Comment: @canton7 hi there, it occurs without async

Comment: this is changed code 

```
 public static Task FuncAsync()
    {
        return new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("FuncAsync"));
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have Rider installed, but much the same thing happens in VS so I'm going to answer for that. I assume something similar happens with Rider.

In VS, we can start the process and then go do Debug -> Attach to Process... to attach a debugger to the process we started. Hit Break then look at the Threads window and we see:

[image: Threads window]

We can see the Main Thread (which is stuck on the `Task.WaitAll)`, and the worker thread. If we double-click the worker thread and look at the Call Stack Window, we see:

[image: Call stack window]

You can see that someone called `Task.Run`. Notably, this isn't your code. The bits of code which are being executed which aren't in the runtime are:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DotNetDeltaApplier.dll!StartupHook.Initialize.AnonymousMethod__0() Unknown
Microsoft.Extensions.DotNetDeltaApplier.dll!StartupHook.ConnectToPipeAndSendCapabilitiesAsync()
Microsoft.Extensions.DotNetDeltaApplier.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.HotReload.ClientInitializationPayload.Write(System.IO.Stream stream)
```

What's `DotNetDeltaApplier`? To google! From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264211/1086121):

> VS 2022 loads dlls into your process: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll, Microsoft.Extensions.DotNetDeltaApplier.dll, etc. if you disable Hot Reload (Project Properties / Debug) it should work (this is probably using COM to communicate between app & reloaded)

(We can see that it's actually using a named pipe rather than COM, but that doesn't matter.)

So VS has loaded an extra DLL into our process (using a [startup hook](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-startup-hook.md)) in order to support Hot Reload (where you change the source code and those changes are patched into a running executable). That extra DLL has taken and blocked a ThreadPool thread, which means that there are no remaining threads in the ThreadPool to run your `Task.Run`.

Indeed, if you find and run the exe directly on your filesystem (rather than launching from VS), it runs to completion.

Comment: OMG You must be a genius !
It works when I turn off the hot-reload setting !
Thanks a lot! hav a good afternoon!